# Hummingbot help hummingbot[connector_base]

Tags: python, importerror, connector

How can I resolve the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hummingbot.connector.connector_base'

when running *Hummingbot* on Windows? I have already installed all the required dependencies and packages, but I am still encountering this error.

I just want to get to the stage where I can actually *hummingbot* on the terminal. All help appreciated

I was expecting the *humingbot* to load after I had loaded the environment and the `humingbot.py` file in the bin folder, but no luck, I have cleared as many errors as I can with *chatgpt* help, but I am now stuck here

Comment: what is the name of the module and what is the name of the file that you have created please ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the `./compile` command before running the bot.

https://docs.hummingbot.org/installation/source/#install-hummingbot